# In Corda, which firewall ports need to be opened for the message queue?

Tags: corda

In Corda, a message queue is used to communicate with other nodes. Which ports need to be open in my firewall to communicate using this message queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Corda 3, you need to open the following ports:

- **Outbound:** You need to open all outbound ports on all IP addresses
- **Inbound:** You only need to open the node's P2P port on every IP address. You configure the node's P2P port using the `p2pAddress` configuration option in the node's `node.conf` file. See https://docs.corda.net/corda-configuration-file.html for further details

Comment: Is there a rationale behind the design for outbound needing all ports open? Any future updates planned to change this?

Comment: Because other network nodes could be listening on any port on any IP address.